# How to send the parameter values to azure data factory using powershell

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to send 2 parameters to data factory pipeline parameters and trigger the pipeline using powershell scripting.
May I know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the pipeline through `Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline` command. It should look like:

```
Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactory $yourADFv2DataFactory -PipelineName "YourAdfv2PipelineName" -ParameterFile .\PipelineParameters.json
```

The PipelineParameters.json file should be like:

```
{
  "parameter_1_name": "parameter_1_value",
  "parameter_2_name": "parameter_2_value"
}
```

You can refer the [Official Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#azure-powershell)

Comment: Is it possible with Azure Data Factory Triggers? I mean can i use same way to update parameters of Azure Data Factory Triggers?